# How to change the background color using classname in angular 6?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular5, angular6

How can I change the background color or image using classname on click ok button.

For Example I have one div,

I can write this code in jquery like this,

```
$(".test").css("background","red");
```

In Javascript

```
document.getElementByClassName('.test').style.background="red";
```

How can I do this is Angular 2 or 4 or 5 or 6?

```js
changebtn():void{
document.querySelector('test').classList.add('newClass');
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
</div>

<button (click)="changeBtn()"></button>
```

I tried this one. But it is not working. Can anyone please help me todo this?

Comment: https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass :)

Comment: Would you not rather want to reference the color VIA a class and use `transitions` to animate the color change?

Answer (score 2):

I think easier way is to declare parameter and use `[style.background]` :

**HTML**

```
<button (click)="changeBtn()" [style.background]="color"></button>
```

**TS**

```
color:string="your first color"

changebtn(){
 //change to your wanted color
  color="red";
}
```

***if you want to use `class` :***

**HTML**

```
<button (click)="changeBtn()" [class]="color"></button>
```

**TS**

```
color:string=""

changebtn(){
 //change to your wanted color
  color="yourClassName";
}
```

**Css:**

```
.yourClassName{}
```

Comment: How to change Border radius? [style.borderRadius]="3px" is this correct?

Comment: @sathishkumar no, it's the real css property, `[style.border-radius]`. And you have to input a string, so `[style.border-radius]="'3px'"`

Comment: @sathishkumar use as  trichetriche said or use my edit(with class)

Comment: I would suggest `[style.border-radius.px]="3"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="test" #changeClass>
</div>

<button (click)="changeBtn()"></button>
```

**In component**

```
import { ElementRef, ViewChild, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@ViewChild('changeClass') elementRef: ElementRef;

constructor(private renderer: Renderer2){}

changebtn = () => {
    this.renderer.addClass(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'new-class');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it something like this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('test')[0]["style"].background="red";
```

Here is Stackblitz working example: [Set background color by ClassName Angular (2/4/5/6)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ri1fk5)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the className property like this:

```
<div [className]="'active'"></div>
```

Now in your `CSS` file you will need to have a class named active (which then changes the background-color or whatever you wish).

Of course this allows you to make it dynamic for example:

```
<div [className]="active ? active :disabled"></div>
```

Now Angular will look for a property named active in the class of the component. Then this will be converted to a boolean and if this boolean is true the active class is applied, otherwise the disabled.

There are other ways which are in the other answers which are also just fine.